# File Upload php syntax error

Tags: php

I'm trying to make this code work again. I did something that made in not echo even the file name I'm trying to access. Please help, I've been looking at this for over an hour already with no avail :(
Note: I can't even echo out the $name in here

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(0);
    if($_POST['submit']){
        //file uploading 
        $name = basename($_FILES['upload']['name']); //name plus extention
        print_r($_FILES['upload']);
        $t_name = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $dir = 'gallery_i';
        $thumbs = 'gallery_t';

        if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir.'/'.$name)){
            $resizeObj = new resize($dir.'/'.$name);//Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 200, 'auto'); //Save image
            $resizeObj -> saveImage($thumbs.'/'.$name, 100);
            echo 'file upload nicely';
            //file upload successfull           
        }           
}
?>


<div class='home'>
    <form method='post' action='other.php'>
        Name: <input class='reg' type='text' name='prodname'/><br/><br/>
        Description:<br/> <textarea class='reg' name='description' rows="4" cols="40">                </textarea> <br/><br/>
        <input type='file' name='upload' />
        <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this page called `other.php`?

Comment: Have you checked file permissions on the directory your trying to move the file to?

Comment: can you set `error_reporting()` to `1` and check it for errors? =) And What do you get from `print_r`? give an output please. Try to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `form` element

Answer (score 7):

You need to use mutlipart form data to upload files:

set the form attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

simple tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Maybe so, but it can still be useful for beginners and I also posted a link to the more detailed spec at World Wide Web consortium if she's like to read more in-depth ;)

Comment: @benedict_w: Agreed. w3schools is like the WikiPedia of programming resource.  It does the job for getting up and going, but eventually you'll need a better resource when you dig into the details or run into technical trouble.  Frankly, I think this dogmatic rejection on SO of all things w3schools is kind of silly, it does have it's useful purpose IMO.

Comment: @mellamokb: +1 for that. I don't link to w3schools, I link to something they wrote.  Don't tell me w3schools is stuffed up, tell me what is wrong with what I specifically linked to.  It's like hating an entire nation because some of it's members are hateful.  That's exactly how racism works...

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` only executes if `move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir.'/'.$name)` returns true. In your case, it is returning false.

You need to determine if

- the file exists (`file_exists($t_name)`)
- is readable (`is_readable($t_name)`)
- the target directory is writable (`is_writable($dir)`)
- no file with the same name already exists (`!is_file($dir . '/' . $name)`)

Only when those conditions are true will `move_uploaded_file` complete successfully.

As noted by benedict_w, you also need to modify your HTML form to add the attribute `enctype` with a value of `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on php's error reporting/display options. Running with those off while develping/debugging is a lot like running a marathon on the side of a cliff at midnight while wearing a blindfold.

In your php.ini:

```
display_errors: 1
error_reporting: E_ALL
```

As well, your script will never work. For file uploads to even have a chance of succeeding, you need to specify

```
<form method="post" action="other.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- missing
```

and you're assuming the upload has succeeded. At bare minimum you should have:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        .... your file handling code
    } else {
        die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['upload']['error']);
    }
}
```